# NodeJS ReactJS deployed app returning a 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

Hopefully someone can help me out as i haven't used NodeJS much. I wanted to demo crawli-io by agustinaliagac, cloned from the below URL https://github.com/agustinaliagac/crawl-io

I've followed the instructions within the readme but i'm getting a 404 when requesting http://localhost:3000/#/results?searchTerm=iPhone

Steps followed below, note i have tried 3A using Docker and without both returning the same result.

1- Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/agustinaliagac/crawl-io.git

2- Install dependencies
cd crawl-io
yarn install:full

3A- Run (without Docker)
yarn start

## Or start backend and frontend independently

yarn start:frontend
yarn start:backend

3B- Run (Docker)
yarn start:docker

Initially when i deployed this i had 'undefined' in the URL, i managed to fix this by adding in the localhost to the .env file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVrVz.jpg)

Comment: Why is this tagged with git? The issue doesn't seem to be caused by it. Remember: _"Do not use [the git] tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository"_

Comment: OK thanks for the feedback.